# dropdown list not loaded in edit form or not selected row according table id

Tags: php, mysql, dropdown

My Below Codes are edit row in database. All is working fine except a two dropdown lists which is dynamically loaded from database. but in edit mode its not loaded all options in list or default row not selected according to row id of database table.

Please tell me what changes need to in below codes.

**My codes :**

```html
<?php
//include database connection file
require_once'functions.php';
// Get the userid
$userid=intval($_GET['id']);
$onerecord=new DB_con();
$sql=$onerecord->fetchonerecord($userid);
$cnt=1;
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
  {
 
  ?>
<?php include('header.php');?>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
    <?php include('sidebar.php');?>

    <div class="main-panel">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation-example-2">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Welcome</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                   

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                       
                        <!-- <li class="dropdown">
                              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    <p>
                                        Dropdown
                                        <b class="caret"></b>
                                    </p>

                              </a>
                              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                              </ul>
                        </li> -->
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <p>Log out</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="separator hidden-lg hidden-md"></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

<!-- content area -->
        <div class="content">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
 <!-- Form Start -->
 
 <div class="col-md-10 " style="float:none; margin:0 auto;">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="header">
                                <h4 class="title">Edit Staff</h4>
                                <a href="allstaff.php" class="btn btn-info btn-fill pull-right " style="margin:-30px 0 0 0 ;" >All Staff</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="content">
                                <form action="update.php" method="post">
                                     <div class="row">  <!-- Row 1 Form  -->
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Name</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['name']);?>">
                                                <input type="hidden"  name="id" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['id']);?>" >
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Email</label>
                                                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['email']);?>">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Phone</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Enter Phone" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['phone']);?>">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">  <!-- Row 2 Form  -->
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">EMP ID</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter EMP ID" name="empid" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['empid']);?>">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Department</label>
                                                <select data-placeholder="Select Department" name="dept" id="" class="form-control select2" >
                                             <!-- <option value="">Select Department</option> -->
                                             
                                             <option  value="<?php if($row['dept']=="Graphics") echo 'selected="selected"';?>"><?php echo htmlentities($row['dept']);?></option>
                                             
                                             
                                             
                                            </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Designation</label>
                                                <select data-placeholder="Select Department" name="desi" id="" class="form-control select2" >
                                             <!-- <option value="">Select Designation</option> -->
                                             
                                             <option  value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['desi']); echo 'selected="selected"';?>"><?php echo htmlentities($row['desi']);?></option>
                                            
                                         
                                            
                                             
                                            </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Address</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Address" name="address" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['address']);?>">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>City</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter City" name="city" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['city']);?>">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>State</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter State" name="state" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['state']);?>">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Pin Code</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Pin Code" name="pcode" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['pcode']);?>">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-12">
                                    <hr>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="">Date of Joining</label>
                                        <input type="date"  value="<?php echo strftime('%Y-%m-%d', strtotime($row['doj']));?>"  placeholder="Enter Date of Joining" name="doj" id="date1" class=" form-control ">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="">PAN Card</label>
                                        <input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['pan']);?>"  placeholder="Enter PAN Card" name="pan" id="" class="form-control ">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="">Adhaar No.</label>
                                        <input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['adhaar']);?>"  placeholder="Enter Adhaar No." name="adhaar" id="" class="form-control ">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-12"><hr></div>
                                <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="">Bank Name</label>
                                         <input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['bname']);?>" name="bname" placeholder="Enter Bank Name." id="" class="form-control ">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="bank_account_no">Bank Account No.</label>
                                         <input type="text" name="bacc" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['bacc']);?>" placeholder="Enter Bank Account No.." id="" class="form-control ">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="ifsc">IFSC Code.</label>
                                         <input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['ifsc']);?>" name="ifsc" placeholder="Enter IFSC Code." id="" class="form-control ">
                                    </div>
                                </div>  
                                </div>       <!-- Row End -->
                                   
                                       
                                <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="ifsc">Account Type</label>
                                        <select required="" name="acct" value="" data-placeholder="Select Account Type" id="" class="form-control select2">
                                            <option value=""></option>
                                            <option  value="1" <?php if($row['acct']=="1") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Saving Account</option>
                                            <option  value="2" <?php if($row['acct']=="2") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Current Account</option>
                                            <option  value="3" <?php if($row['acct']=="3") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >Salary Account</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="ifsc">Monthly Salary</label>
                                         <input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['msal']);?>" name="msal" placeholder="Enter Monthly Salary" id="" class="form-control ">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
        
                                </div>       <!-- Row End -->
                                <?php } ?>  

                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-fill pull-right" name="save">Update</button>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
<!-- Form End -->

                    
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- Content area end -->


        <footer class="footer">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                
                
            </div>
        </footer>

    </div>
</div>


</body>

    <!--   Core JS Files   -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--  Charts Plugin -->
    <script src="assets/js/chartist.min.js"></script>

    <!--  Notifications Plugin    -->
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-notify.js"></script>

    <!--  Google Maps Plugin    -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY_HERE"></script>

    <!-- Light Bootstrap Table Core javascript and methods for Demo purpose -->
    <script src="assets/js/light-bootstrap-dashboard.js?v=1.4.0"></script>

    <!-- Light Bootstrap Table DEMO methods, don't include it in your project! -->
    <script src="assets/js/demo.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('form').parsley();
            CKEDITOR.replaceAll( 'cke' );  
            $('.select2').select2(); 
            $( ".date" ).datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat:'dd-M-yy',
        });
            $( ".date2" ).datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            maxDate:0,
            dateFormat:'dd-M-yy',
        });
 
 
        });
    </script>
   
</html>
```

Comment: Any one help to solve my codes bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some steps should be possible:

1. add selected in the select

   ```
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Department</label>
    <select selected data-placeholder="Select Department" name="dept" id="" class="form-control select2" >                  
   <option  value="<?php if($row['dept']=="Graphics") echo 'selected="selected"';?>"><?php echo htmlentities($row['dept']);?></option>                                             
     </select>
    </div>
   ```
2. If it's still an error Change the logic in the options

   ```
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Department</label>
    <select selected data-placeholder="Select Department" name="dept" id="" class="form-control select2" >
   <option <?php echo ($row['dept'] == "Graphics")?'selected':''; ?> value="<?php $row['dept'];?>"><?php echo htmlentities($row['dept']);?></option> 
    </select>
    </div>
   ```

3.Check again using var_dump maybe $row['dept'] hasn't got the value yet

Btw I usually use the above source code with loop logic